# Request refresh of LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, listview

I am using the `LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP` to show some text in my ListCtrl until it gets some content. The problem I am facing is I can't seem to find a way to refresh this text and effectively force ListCtrl to send this notification more than once.

Is there a way to tell ListCtrl to refresh the "markup"?

Comment: You'll have to make it empty again.

Comment: Alright, but what if it remains empty for some time and I want to trigger two messages depending on the state of the app? Basically, my list never had any items to begin with. Should I insert a dummy and clear immediately? Sounds like that should do the trick.

Comment: FWIW, even after I clear the items from my control, I never get the LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP query again. It appears to cache it indefinitely...

Answer (score 6):

Well this is a fairly old thread however i came across to this and will provide an answer for anyone that came to same place like me.

It is possible to resend LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP message to the listview by sending   LVM_RESETEMPTYTEXT = (LVM_FIRST + 84) message to the listview or by obtaining IListView interface  and executing ResetEmptyText method. In this way you can conditionaly change or clear the empty text :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. It's a shame we have to resort to undocumented messages for something so trivial and obvious. But that's just typical for Microsoft these days.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at the source, and it appears that the listview control sends the `LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP` query exactly once and caches the result.

Therefore, I believe that the only way to get the behavior you're looking for is to recreate the control as appropriate.